# ASPX Login Controls work on everyone's computer except mine

Tags: asp.net, .aspxauth

I'm using VSEW 2013 and running windows 10.

I created a login page (Login.aspx) and a signup page (SignUp.aspx).  I used the standard controls and did not add any code behind to them.  They are out of the box controls.

What works:

1. Creating an account on signup.aspx page
2. Validating user login on Login.aspx page
3. On my computer, after login, it shows that I didn't log in yet.  But when my friends test it, they don't have any problems with it.

Here is a drop box link to all of the files and you can test it yourself and see that it works.
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/do3f533s0hacy4x/AADuWBbIBpaxDy7SIPG9_7s6a?dl=0

Username: kyle
password 123456

However, signup.aspx works (well it won't send you an email because I didn't do that yet) so you can create your own account.

I've tried:

1. Verified that cookies are enables
2. Disabled Antivirus
3. Disabled Firewall
4. Checked Windows Defender (it's off)
5. Tested in Chrome, Edge, and Firefox.
6. Deleted all localhost cookies.

I cannot figure out why my computer won't let me log in successfully but everyone else can.

Please help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your web.config, for some odd reason this section is there:

```
<system.webServer>
   <modules>
     <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
   </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

This section coupled with the fact that your authentication mode is set to forms:

```
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="Forms" />
  ...
</system.web>
```

Would make it so that authentication wouldn't work at all, which is like what your describing. Try removing that first section, if you want to keep using Forms Authentication.

It's odd that this configuration would work on other computers, I can't explain that, but I would try removing that section of code where FormsAuthentication is being turned off and see if that helps.